# Remoção de valores repetidos entre duas tabelas com VBA

Tags: sql, vba, tabela-html, microsoft-access

Preciso de ajuda com a eliminação de valores iguais entre duas tabelas.

Tenho duas tabelas com vários campos diferentes, elas possuem um campo em comum chamado celular, uma tabela possui o número no formato 55119xxxxxxxx e a outra o possui no formato +55119xxxxxxxx. Meu objetivo é eliminar os registros onde os celulares são iguais (de ambas tabelas).
Fiz um código em VBA para eliminar os registros nos quais estes campos possuem o mesmo valor (independente do conteúdo dos outros campos), veja abaixo:

```
set rstb1 = currentDb.openrecordset("SELECT * FROM tabela1") 'Recordset da primeira tabela
set rstb2 = currentDb.openrecordset("SELECT * FROM tabela2") 'Recordset da segunda tabela

Do While Not rstb1.EOF
    Do While Not rstb2.EOF
        If rstb1.Fields("celular") = Right(rstb2.Fields("celular"), 13) Then
        rstb1.Delete
        rstb2.Delete
        rstb1.MoveNext
        End If
        rstb2.MoveNext
    Loop
    rstb1.MoveNext
    rstb2.MoveFirst
Loop
```

Obs: os celulares só se repetem uma vez.

O código funciona, porém demora muito para realizar as remoções, já que cada tabela tem mais de 30 mil registros, o que daria cerca de 9 milhões de repetições no loop acima. Preciso de um meio mais rápido para fazer essas remoções.

Answer (score -1):

Eu tentaria usar:

```
Application.ScreenUpdate = False
Application.Calculation  = xlCalculationManual
```

No início do código e:

```
Application.ScreenUpdate = True
Application.Calculation  = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

No final dele.